# How to close jQuery SimpleModal external page popup on popup page event?

Tags: c#, jquery, simplemodal

I have an asp.net c# project and need to open another page (within the project) as a popup using jQuery SimpleModel plugin, and close it when user clicks on a link on the popup page. (This link also has some serverside code.)

I could open a page with this code,

```
$('a#Test').click(function() {
            $.modal('<iframe src="PopUp.aspx" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
                closeHTML: "",
                containerCss: {
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    borderColor: "#fff",
                    height: 450,
                    padding: 0,
                    width: 830
                },
                overlayClose: true
            });
        });
```

but can't figure it out how to close it on click event of popup page.

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if my response does not solve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PopUp.aspx, you'd want to use:

```
parent.$.modal.close(); // or parent.jQuery.modal.close();
```

In the same page, you'd use:

```
$.modal.close(); // or jQuery.modal.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work fine for me:

```
('a#Test').click(function() {
    $.modal('<iframe src="PopUp.aspx" height="450" width="830" style="border:0"/><p><center><input value="Close" name="Close" class="CloseBtn" type="button" /></center></p>', {
        closeHTML: "",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderColor: "#fff",
            height: 450,
            padding: 0,
            width: 830
        },
        closeClass:('CloseBtn')
    });
});
```